# What is the best way to query data conditionally in MongoDB (node.js)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs

What I'm basically trying to do, is to render different look on the front-end (react.js) based on whether the user is part of the group or not. I tried conditional querying, looping on front-end etc.

What would be your approach to tackle this problem?

My last try was an aggregation, but it doesn't return any value:

```
      Role.aggregate(
      [
        {
          $project: {_id: roleID, 
           UserInRole: { $cond: { 
           if:{ userList: { $in: [userID]}}, then: true, else: false} }}

        }
   ]
            )
```

Comment: "based on whether the user is part of the group or not" - can you elaborate on that condition, and include some of the code you have tried?

Comment: The problem is that whatever I tried failed.

Comment: What I want is something like e.g. Facebook. As long as you're not in a group, you see a join button. As soon as you're in, you see leave button. What is the process behind it in simple theory?

Comment: Can you provide an example of at least one thing you tried? Otherwise how can anyone suggest improvements? [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) provides instructions on how to ask a good question

Comment: I added it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To come up with a functioning MongoDB query that determines whether a user is part of a group requires an understanding of how you're structuring your database and groups collection. One way to structure that is like so:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("594ea5bc4be3b65eeb8705d8"),
    "group_name": "...",
    "group_members": [
        {
            "user_id": ObjectId("<same one from users collection"), 
            "user_name": "Alice", 
            "user_profile_picture": "<link_to_imag_url>"
        },
        {
            "user_id": ObjectId("<same one from users collection"),
            "user_name": "Bob",
            "user_profile_picture": "<link_to_imag_url>"
        },
        ....
    ]
}
```

Your group document/object can have attributes for things like it's name, creation date, description, etc. One of the attributes should be "group_members" which can be used when doing your query to see if a user (based on id) is part of a specific group.

The MongoDB [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator seems like a great choice to satisfy your use case (if you're using a similar group data structure to example one. Further down on that $elemMatch page is a section on [Array of Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#array-of-embedded-documents). You can do a query like:

```
db.groups.find({
    _id: ObjectId("<id of group you're checking"),
    group_members: {
        $elemMatch: { user_id: ObjectId("<user id of user you're checking>") } 
    }
})
```

That will return either 1 or 0 results. 1 if there is a group with that `_id` and a `group_members` array that contains an element that has the user id specified, otherwise 0.

Now to use that in Node, you can use the [MongoDB NodeJS Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/) in conjunction with an [Express](https://expressjs.com/) web server:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test'; // change test to whichever db you added the collections to

app.get('/partOfGroup', (req, res) => {
    if (req.query.groupId == null || req.query.userId == null) {
        return res.send('Must include both groupId and userId')
    } else {
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            var collection = db.collection('groups');
            collection.findOne({
                _id: ObjectID(req.query.groupId),
                group_members: {
                    $elemMatch: { user_id: req.query.userId}
                }
            }, function(err, result) {
                return res.send(result != null)
            })
        })
    }
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000');
});
```

With that up and running, you can go to the url http://localhost:3000/partOfGroup?groupId=594ea5bc4be3b65eeb8705d8&userId=12345 and it should return true or false depending on if there's a group with id 594ea5bc4be3b65eeb8705d8 and user with id 12345 in that group.

From your front-end code, make a request to that url when a logged in user visits a group page, replacing the group id and user id appropriately. The response you get will determine whether to display a "Join" or "Leave" button.

Comment: Thank you, that looks brilliant. Can't wait to try it tomorrow.